# Checking out from VisualSVN with SVN+SSH:// from Linux

Tags: visualsvn-server, cross-platform

[image]

I've seen a few references to people accessing their VisualSVN server with the svn:// protocol despite visualSVN not *technically* supporting it (due to it still pulling from stock SVN for windows). I have an older Linux client fileserver that for reasons not worth getting into here, won't support http:// for SVN. I've set up an SSH client on the windows host server that I'm able to reach from the Linux client server with the

```
ssh --assorted-command stuff /server
```

but I'm not having luck pulling off

```
svn "command" svn+ssh://stuff/etc
```

style commands.

How can I check out stuff on the host windows visualsvn server from my linux client server?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use svn or svn+ssh access schema by some reason, build your own Subversion server. Do not use VisualSVN Server for this task. VisualSVN Server supports HTTP(S) access only and I'd strongly recommend installing up-to-date Subversion 1.9 client on the Linux machine. It has to support HTTP(S) via Serf library (`libserf`).

Even if you enable `svnserve` that comes with VisualSVN Server, you will miss most of the VisualSVN Server features like repository and permissions management through Microsoft Management Console, Active Directory security integration, VDFS replication and much much more.

PS Read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.svnserve) before asking. Your approach in trying to setup svn / svn+ssh access is completely wrong.

Comment: The client SVN on the Linux server is actually partly the reason I can't get http:// protocol. I can't upgrade or change the SVN client due to legacy reasons too lengthy to get into (believe me, I've tried). I do have more control over the host server, although it has to stay Windows for other reasons so that cuts down my server options. I don't have much experience setting up SVN on a windows machine, so yea, kind of winging that bit.